# libreoffice calc - vary column on drag-down

Tags: worksheet-function, copy-paste, openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Say I have some data in sheet `Sheet_A` on `R2:AA2`

I now want to reference that data in `Sheet_B` in `B2:B10`

How do I do that?

If I write

```
 Sheet_B.B2 = Sheet_A.R$2
```

And then drag down, it will result in

```
 Sheet_B.B3 = Sheet_A.R$2
```

But I want

```
 Sheet_B.B3 = Sheet_A.S$2
```

Comment: I don't use libreoffice, but in MS Excel I'd use something like `Offset(Sheet_A!R2,Row()-2,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OFFSET function works well here:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet_A.$R$2;0;ROW()-2)
```

Alternatively, use ADDRESS and INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;16+ROW();;;"Sheet_A"))
```

Documentation is at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Address,_Indirect,_Offset,_Index.

Comment: Works well, thank you. But didn't you use one too many ``;`` in the ``ADDRESS``? Also, any way to see the column numbers?

Comment: Apparently the number of `ADDRESS` parameters depends on the version.  I used LibreOffice which takes [five parameters](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ADDRESS).  To show column numbers in row 1, enter `=COLUMN()` in cell A1 and then fill right.